# AppShell Tabbar icons do not change color on iOS

Tags: maui, .net-maui

I have a .net maui application with AppShell that defines a tabbar with this code:

```
<TabBar>
    <Tab Title="{x:Static resources:Strings.HomeTitle}">
        <Tab.Icon>
            <FontImageSource FontFamily="MaterialIconsRound" Glyph="home" />
        </Tab.Icon>
        <ShellContent>
            <dashboard:DashboardPage />
        </ShellContent>
    </Tab>

    <Tab Title="{x:Static resources:Strings.StatisticsTitle}">
        <Tab.Icon>
            <FontImageSource FontFamily="MaterialIconsRound" Glyph="donut_small" />
        </Tab.Icon>
        <ShellContent Title="{x:Static resources:Strings.StatisticsTitle}">
            <statistics:StatisticSelectorPage />
        </ShellContent>
    </Tab>

    <Tab Title="{x:Static resources:Strings.MoreTitle}">
        <Tab.Icon>
            <FontImageSource FontFamily="MaterialIconsRound" Glyph="more_horiz" />
        </Tab.Icon>
        <ShellContent>
            <overflowMenu:OverflowMenuPage />
        </ShellContent>
    </Tab>
</TabBar>
```

On Android the icons do change correctly the color depending on the device theme or when they are selected. On iOS only the text changes.
[image]
[image]

Is that a bug or do I have to set a specific style for that?

Answer (score 2):

There is a known issue about this problem. And this issue has been moved to the Backlog milestone.

You can follow it up here: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/8244 .

Thanks for your support and feedback for maui.

Comment: There is a workaround in the linked maui issue that involves using a style with a trigger to update the color.